# Send "@" sign containing data through Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

My code is like Below.

```
$.ajax({               
    url:'http:://www.sample.com/checkmail/'+$('#txtemail').val(),
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('#response').html(data);
        if(data!="Success")                 
        {
            $('#txtemail').css("background-color","#FF8A8D");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#txtemail').css("background-color","white");
        }
    }
});
```

Above code works when passing data without '@' sign

Example:

```
//passing Hello
txtemail = "Hello"

//ajax response message in firefox
GET http://www.example.com/checkmail/Hello 200 OK 503ms
```

But if i pass email like below it gives error

```
Example: 
//passing hello
txtemail = "hello@eee.com"

//ajax response message in firefox
GET http://www.example.com/checkmail/hello@eee.com 400 Bad Request 26ms
```

Any Suggestions How to overcome this matter

Comment: You have a typo in your URL: `http:://`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the E-Mail address.

```
url:'http://www.sample.com/checkmail/'+encodeURIComponent($('#txtemail').val()),
```

`@` is a reserved character in a URL (for the `username:password@domain` scheme) and needs to be percent encoded.

Comment: Thank You. i replace @ sign with %40 when sending email. again end point i have to replace again (%40 to @). I did it long way. Thank You for the easy method.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to encode the url as Unicron said u can also use the escape() function for this....

```
url:'http://www.sample.com/checkmail/'+escape($('#txtemail').val())
```

Comment: Don't use `escape()`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent